# use many lms or random effects (lmer) to estimate a bunch of slopes?

Tags: random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, lm, regression-coefficients

I have what is probably a very simple question, but I just need someone to verify my thinking.

I have a dataset that consists of a variable (var1) measured at 3 time points for about 80 people. At each time point, there are 13 measurements of var1 and the dependent variable per person. I would like to estimate the 'concordance' or 'strength of the relationship' between var1 and the dependent variable for each person at each time point, and then use these concordances (really regression slopes) in further analyses. I see 2 ways of doing this:

1) estimate all the regression slopes for each person:time combo using lm and then use these in subsequent models.

2) construct a random effects model: lmer(dependent ~ (var1|id:time)) from which I could then extract the estimates of the slope for each person at each time...

I think that the 1st solution is probably the best, as it doesn't make as many assumptions about the distribution from which to draw the estimates of the slopes. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: "best" in what sense?  I think it depends what you're trying to do.  If it's just getting the best predictive model, econometricians sometimes use [Hausman tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausman_test) for this purpose.  Or see [this](http://polmeth.wustl.edu/media/Paper/ClarkLinzerREFEMar2012.pdf) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630214/hausmans-specification-test-for-glmer-from-lme4)

Comment: I'm not really interested in a predictive model between these two variables per se. The strength of the relationship between the two should vary across people and it's this variance that I'd like to use in further models. I.e. create a metric of the concordance between the two that can be used in subsequent analyses. That's why I initially thought about just calculating all the slopes individually (or could use correlation coefficients). But then I became uncertain if I should estimate them simultaneously using a random-effects model. I expect I'm needlessly complicating things!

Comment: Just today I came across this article about Stein's paradox:  statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/other/Article1977.pdf
Seems like a useful way to conceptualize the difference between fixed and random effects.

Comment: Also, instead of many lm's you could get the same result by `lm(depvar~var:time:ID)`.  With three periods, this will be very noisy.